# Is this correct "I'll be looking forward to helping.. ? Read on please

Tags: grammar

First of all some background. An acquaintance asked by email if I'm willing to offer advice on a project he's starting to develop. I answered yes for sure.He responded Wonderful,Stay tuned. I have no idea when I will receive the info to give my advice. This email was a few weeks ago.

Today I decided to let him know I'm still interested, a little reminder.

I wrote "I'll be looking forward to helping xyz (xyz- his name)."

A friend told me my above response sounds like you aren't yet but will be in the future. I didn't consider this before sending it.

He knows I want to help and it sounds like this project is a work in progress.I'm waiting to hear from him so I can offer advice.

What I wrote does it convey yes I'm looking forward to helping you? My friend is right? Or is this not a correct sentence and should be worded differently?  Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 5):

"I'm looking forward to helping..." is the correct sentence; but at the same time your intended meaning to be willing to help is obvious.

Comment: Thank you.I should have wrote I'm looking forward to helping. It sounds better.

Answer (score 2):

The more appropriate form, and certainly more common, would be "I look forward to...".

From the perspective of a native American English speaker, although it is certainly possible to read "I'll be looking forward to..." as lacking interest at the moment, but expecting to be interested in the future, I would not read the sentence that way.

First, the context of the situation - at least as you have described it - makes it very clear that this is a project which you are interested in working on now, and would like to get on board with as soon as you can. It isn't a situation in which there would be some combination of factors preventing you from getting engaged with the project immediately, e.g. having to meet an intermediary and completing paperwork *before* being able to do work (in which case although "I look forward to" would still be preferable to "I'll be looking forward to", the latter form is less inaccurate).

Second, without there being some prior indication of disinterest, there should be no reason to assume it is so. By saying "I'll be looking forward to helping him", you're saying - literally - that you, right now, expect that in the future you will look forward to helping him. There are no indications that you looking forward to doing so is conditional on some factor being present (or not present).

All in all, it still conveys the intent that you sought to express - that you remain interested in working on the project - just without using the most "natural" way of doing so.

Comment: Thank you. I haven't hesitated in helping or changing my mind. So he should know Im interested.I was concerned about my wording, if it was correct or  would convey the wrong message. I look forward to  does indeed sound better.

Answer (score 0):

I'd make a different choice here: "I'm still available to help you with *thing* if you want me to."

This phrasing reminds them that the help is still available, but also asks whether the help is still wanted. Sometimes it's useful or even necessary to give someone the chance to say, "I figured it out, thanks!" because they've forgotten your offer. This lets them know that either option is fine for you.

Answer (score -1):

Your wording of "I'll be looking forward to helping" is okay. Most sentences can be worded various ways. For its intended purpose, I think yours is fine. I would expect the sentence to have the pronoun you: "I'll be looking forward to helping you." However, that was not your question. It should be clear to him that you are interested.

Comment: Thank you. The sentence does sound better with using "you" at the end of instead of the name. Dont worry with regards to it not being my question.I appreciate the help.

Answer (score -1):

It's fine as is, but it rings with "ings." Consider "I look forward to helping [you]."

Comment: Why on earth would someone down-vote my suggestion? I guess that's the way things work on Internet.